# How to prevent the y-axis from squishing the labels when using facet_wrap in ggplot/ggplotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

In my example, I'm trying to get the labels on the y-axis to not be squished together. Is there a way to do this using ggplot2 or ggplotly? Here's a reproducible example:

```
mpg2 <- subset(mpg, manufacturer %in% c("audi", "chevrolet", 
"dodge","ford","honda","hyundai","jeep","land rover","lincoln","mercury","nissan", "pontiac", 
 "subaru",  "volkswagen"))

base <- ggplot(mpg2, aes(displ, hwy)) + 
geom_blank() + 
xlab(NULL) + 
ylab(NULL)
ggplotly(base + facet_wrap(~manufacturer, ncol = 1))
```

[image]

Please note: I don't want to make ncol more than 1. I want to keep it this way. I'm trying to prevent it from being squished together. Thank you!

Comment: There is no room.

Comment: Isn't there a way to decrease the size of the y labels itself?

Comment: Yes, `base + theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=rel(0.5))`. Set the `rel` value to whatever you wish. You can also increase the vertical dimension of the output plot, relative to the horizontal dimension. How to do that will depend on what output method you're using.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the actual numbers on y_axis. Does that just change the size of the title of the y axis? I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: Never mind that seems to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @eipi10 for his comment

```
mpg2 <- subset(mpg, manufacturer %in% c("audi", "chevrolet", 
"dodge","ford","honda","hyundai","jeep","land rover","lincoln","mercury","nissan", "pontiac", 
 "subaru",  "volkswagen"))

base <- ggplot(mpg2, aes(displ, hwy)) + 
geom_blank() + 
xlab(NULL) + 
ylab(NULL)

ggplotly(base + facet_wrap(~manufacturer, ncol = 1) + theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=rel(0.5)))
```